# link_to image_tag with inner text or html in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I want to output the following with Ruby on Rails `link_to` and `image_tag` methods:

```
<a href="#">Lorem Ipsum <img src="/images/menu-arrow-down.gif"></a>
```

What would be a good way in Rails?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Why not just use a link to and image tag?

```
<%= link_to "hiii #{image_tag(yourimagepath)}", "link_path" %>
```

You could also try the appending done above (`string + image_tag`), but it will throw an error if one of those things becomes `nil`. Using interpolation, it will just show a blank image(or string) if it is `nil`.

For Rails 3, you will need to use `html_safe`:

```
<%= link_to "hiii #{image_tag(yourimagepath)}".html_safe, "link_path" %>
```

Comment: This does not work in Rails 3, @Fazley's answer below works. Due to the asset pipeline, there is no need to use images/ in the path either.

Comment: this is actually printing out the text of the image tag for me

Answer (score 91):

You can use blocks as an alternative to the string interpolation with correct usage `html_safe`. For example:

```
<%= link_to '#' do %>
  Lorem Ipsum <%= image_tag('/images/menu-arrow-down.gif') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 works when you want to wrap a span & class around the text as well :)

Answer (score 35):

Or a shorter way is

```
<%= link_to image_tag('image/someimage.png') + "Some text", some_path %>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
link_to(image_tag("image.png", :alt =>  "alt text", :class =>"anyclass"), image_url)
```

Answer (score 3):

I cannot seem to figure out how to add a comment to @corroded's answer.  However, if you are using Rails 3, his answer will not work as expected.  It might not be immediately obvious how to fix this, at least it wasn't for me.  I knew I needed to add **html_safe**, but put it in the wrong place.  In retrospect, it was obvious, but I thought I would include it here for others like me who make the "rookie" mistake.

```
<%= link_to "hiii #{image_tag(yourimagepath)}".html_safe, "link_path" %>
```

be careful though, if you are using a user assignable variable for "hiii" you need to sanitize it first.

```
<%= link_to (h(my_model.some_string) + image_tag(yourimagepath)).html_safe,
            "link_path" %>
```

Note that there is no issue with my_model.some_string or yourimagepath being nil because both h() and image_tag() return strings when passed **nil**.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this approach in HAML

```
= link_to root_path do
  = image_tag "ic_launcher.png", size: "16x16"
  Home
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cool way to use a link_to to include an image, and a mailto href with Text (displayed next to the image):

```
<%= link_to image_tag("image.png") + " some@email.com", 
                         href: "mailto:some@email.com" %>
```

Giving you something like this in your view (the entire image and text become an mailto href):

[image: hyperlinked image and text with mailto]

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked just fine:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(<URL>,style),<URL>) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found out this also which worked.

```
link_to(image_tag("/images/linkd.png",:alt=>"twt"){},:href=>"some_url",:target=>"_blank")
```