# Rails - link_to with image_tag + text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, link-to

```
<%= link_to ((image_tag 'image.png'), 
        url_for({:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name'}), 
            :class => 'quick', 
            :remote => true) %>
```

This part of code will generate me **image.png** as a link. I would need to this image append some text (image + text), I tried something like a:

```
<%= link_to ((image_tag 'image.png', 'text'), 
        url_for({:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name'}), 
            :class => 'quick', 
            :remote => true) %>
```

And similar ways, but each of these attempts ended with an error message about bad syntax...  Could anyone help me, please, how I should set it right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387122/link-to-image-tag-with-text-in-rails

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this.

```
<%= link_to image_tag('/images/image.png') + "some extra text", url_for({:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name'}), :class => 'quick', :remote => true %>
```

Comment: Also the image_tag bit needs to come first, if it comes after the '+' it will be escaped

Comment: You should change the answer according Rails 3 syntax.

Answer (score 12):

A slightly sexier solution?

```
<%= link_to image_tag("image.png", :alt => "Image Description", :class => "css"), root_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag('image.png') + text, 
        url_for({:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name'}), 
            :class => 'quick', 
            :remote => true) %>
```

The first argument is the text part and with image_tag you create HTML, but you can easily append stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and it works just fine:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("logo.jpg"), controller: 'welcome' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it`s too late, but maybe someone trying to find the answer, so.
The right answer is:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url), line_items_path(product_id: product), method: :post, remote: true %>
```

In this case, we need to specify what exact action we want to perform, by clicking on this image, if we are using button_to helper, we don't need to specify the action, but button helper doesn`t support image tags