# image_tag and added extra folders in assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I added an icon folder within my `assets/images` folder for my project in rails.

```
/assets
  /images
    /icons
      icon1
```

I am a beginner in RoR. From my understanding `image_tag` will look for images in `assets/images`. What should I do if I added an icons folder? I want ot keep my images sorted

This is what I currently have

```
    <%= link_to image_tag("facebook.png", alt: "facebook"), 'FB LINK' %>
    <%= link_to image_tag("youtube.png", alt: "Subscribe"), 'YOUTUBE LINK' %>
    <%= link_to image_tag("twitter.png", alt: "follow"), 'TWITTER LINK' %>
```

Also, how would I shrink these images to a smaller size?

Comment: can you not just include the folder in the path?  "icons/facebook.png"?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag  Have you looked at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414842/rails-3-link-to-with-image-tag-text and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387122/link-to-image-tag-with-text-in-rails