# link on image and text in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to convert this into ruby on rails code :

```
<a href="#"><span>Log out</span><%= image_tag("images/log-out.png") %></a>
```

When trying this one:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("images/log-out.png", :border => 0 ), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

I'm getting a link on the image. But i also need to add span with text.I tried this but its not working:-

```
 <%= link_to "<span>Log out</span>"+image_tag("images/log-out.png", :border => 0 ), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Please refer this same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387122/link-to-image-tag-with-text-in-rails

Comment: Saw but it didn't work. It was simply printing out the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
 <%= link_to raw("<span>Log out</span>") + image_tag("images/log-out.png", :border => 0 ), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy this one worked for me. I will accept this as an answer after some time as stack won't allow me to do it now.