# Changing Ruby "Show, Edit, Destroy" tags to clickable image icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, hyperlink

I've generated a scaffold in rails for a to-do list app, and for each listing there is a default "Show", "Edit", and "Destroy" link at the end of each one. I want to know how to change these links to icons that I can click on to use those actions.

Here is the code that I'm currently trying, I only edited the "Show" button:

```
`<td>
  <%= link_to image_tag(url("http://i1051.photobucket.com/albums/s423/Kira-Banks/show-1.png")), project %>
 </td>

 <td>
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %>
 </td>

 <td>
   <%= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
 </td>`
```

Comment: Possibly duplicated. See here 2nd answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387122/link-to-image-tag-with-text-in-rails

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you! I couldn't find an answer in the searches.