# How to put a button (and link) inside an .inky Action Mailer template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, inky

This is probably really simple, but how can I make this link_to

```rb
<%= link_to("Send " + @user.first_name + " a message" , @conversation) %>
```

into a button in an `.inky` file?

Note: here is how to make a button in an `.inky` file (I just don't know how to put the two together):

```
  <button class="large" href="#">Sign Up</button>
```

#### Attempts so far

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5387340/5783745) answer might help, but I still can't get code that works

I'm also trying something like `link_to(raw(...), @conversation)`, but again I can't quite get it working

I also tried this, but the button doesn't appear and the link doesn't work

```
<% label = "Send " + @user.first_name + " a message" %>
<% raw_html = '<button class="large">' + label + '</button>' %>
<%= link_to(raw(raw_html), @conversation) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was really overthinking it. You don't need link_to at all, just give the url directly to the `href` attribute of the `button` tag. It's that simple

```
<button class="large" href="<%= conversation_url(@conversation) %>"><%= "Send " + @user.first_name + " a message" %></button>
```

[image]